# Analysing and Plotting OMNET++ results

Tags: statistics, omnet++, veins

I have run a VEINS/OMNET++ simulation using `Cmdenv`. Usually I used OMNET++ IDE to run simulation and would analyze the results within IDE. But now the results are on a server, is there any easier(convenient) way to analyze the results without importing it into OMNET++ IDE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various ways to analyze results without relying on the IDE.

- One example would be to use R and the [omnetpp](https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp-resultfiles/tree/master/R-package) Package.
  There is also an extensive [tutorial](https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp-resultfiles/wiki/Tutorial-for-the-omnetpp-r-package) explaining how to install and use the package.
- Another way could be to write a parser for `.sca`and `.vec`files in Python and then analyze the files using [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to write an R script using omnetpp package, this is what i am currently doing, for the same purpose.

Under your server you can install R, then run the script with Rscript command

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent tutorial on how to analyze and plot OMNeT++ results using Python: https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/pandas/

Essentially:

1. Create a CSV file out of the OMNeT++ result files: `scavetool x *.vec -o measurements.csv`
2. Read the CSV files with pandas: `results = pd.read_csv('measurements.csv')`
3. Filter, edit, and plot the data using `pandas`, `numpy`, and `matplotlib` as usual

Answer (score 0):

There is another option if you are familiar with SQL query: Change the setting in the config file *omnetpp.ini* to export the result vector file to *.sqlite* format instead of the normal *.vec* extension. This can be done following the instruction from [Omnet++'s guide](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ana-sim:sqlite-result-files).

The database schema is quite straightforward, which can be seen from any Sqlite Db Browser tool or from the [Apendix section](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:result-file-formats:sqlite) of the same Omnet++ guide.

With the output *.sqlite* file, you can use any language supportting sqlite of your choice to query and analyze on that data file. Python also has a built in [sqlite3 module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) that worked quite well.